# Struts2 jQuery Plugin Showcase - Nested Accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, jsp, struts2, jquery-ui-accordion, struts2-jquery

Requirement : To create nested accordion using Struts2 Jquery UI widget of http://struts.jgeppert.com/

Code Snippet:

```xml
<sj:accordion id="accordion" heightStyle="content" animate="true">
    <sj:accordionItem title="Section 1">

        <!--  Start Nested Accordion -->
        <sj:accordion id="accordion2" heightStyle="content"  animate="true" >
            <sj:accordionItem title="Sub section1.1">Sub section 1</sj:accordionItem>
            <sj:accordionItem title="Sub section1.2">Sub section 2</sj:accordionItem>
        </sj:accordion>
        <!--  End Nested Accordion -->

    </sj:accordionItem>
    <sj:accordionItem title="Section 2">
        This is section 2
    </sj:accordionItem>                     
</sj:accordion>
```

Issue: Parent accordionItem of nested accordion collapsing when nested accordion item is clicked.

Comment: I don't think it could handle it out-of-the-box. Take a look [at this](http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion.html)